# insert frame title and subtitle for image in android?

Tags: android, image

I want to add frame to image with title and subtitle. The thing that I want to do is as follows : There are number of styled frames available and user selects any picture from the phone memory or takes a picture from camera, now on selecting any frame that picture should be in that frame. Also below that frame there should be title and subtitle of the image.

I hope I have made it clear of what I want to know.

Answer (score 0):

As for the image frame I believe the easiest way to achieve it would be to use a nine patched image as the image background. By defining the padding ans stretch areas your frame will always be correct size for any image.

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

For title and and subtitle you should use TextViews under the image. Just define your own layout for the whole component.

Comment: I think this is not what I want. The result of adding frame title and subtitle should also return another image not a layout. I want something similar to http://www.frameshow.com/index.php. The images should fit inside such frames and there will be title and subtitle to it too.

Comment: I think this is not what I want. The result of adding frame title and subtitle should also return another image not a layout. I want something similar to frameshow.com/index.php. The images should fit inside such frames and there will be title and subtitle to it too.